# Service Fabric - create net core 2.0 project, but target framework is 4.6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I create empty service fabric project and add a single .net core 2.0 aspnet statefull service. When I check the properties of the web project, the target framework is 4.6, not .net core 2.0.

My visual studio is 2017 latest update and with .net core 2.0 sdk installed. The project structure is according to .net core.

Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Fabric itself is built on top of the .net framework. The web project is still ASP.net core, though. The Microsoft.AspNet.Core libraries target netstandard2.0, which .NET 4.6 implements.

Note:
If you create an ASP.net Core web project using Visual Studio 2017 you can actually switch between .NET Core and .NET Framework. If you select .NET Framework (in the top left dropdown) it will disable the 'Enable Docker Support' checkbox.